# Update win 7 MBR with 2nd disk win 10

Tags: windows-7, mbr, windows-10-preview

On the same box I have a hdd with win 7 & a hdd with win 10. Can I get the win 7 to detect that I've added a win 10 disk.

I installed the win 10 while using that box, but the 1st disk wasn't attached.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into Windows 7 and use [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to [add a new boot menu entry](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/bcd-based/) for Windows 10:

[image: 1]

(Under *Type* most likely Windows 10 will not be listed, but selecting Windows 8 should work.)

I would recommend however that you make the Windows 10 drive the first boot device and add a Windows 7 entry to its boot menu instead.

Comment: This worked for adding an entry, it was misnamed, but would not boot. I'm going to work on it a bit